# Output lenght of a PIC microcontroller dictated by a pulse

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

I´m new to PIC programming (but used to C language) and started using the 12F675 for my first project.

One part of this project is a trigger that when activated (high state) makes the PIC send an output. However, the duration of this output is dictated by another input, a cutoff, that goes from high to low, stays low for some time, then goes to high state again.
The duration of this pulse will vary depending on the system I´ll use it on. What I want is the output of the PIC staying on high state from the time the trigger is activated to the first time the cutoff goes from high to low, so the falling edge of the signal, and, even if i keep the trigger activated, the output wont go high again until a rising edge from the trigger input occurs again.

I´ll post a graph i made in MS Paint (sorry for the low quality) to show better what i want --> [input and output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u3S7.png)

I hope this question isn´t confusing (english isn´t my first language).

Thanks in advance for any reply

EDIT 1: I forgot to state the core of this question. The thing is that I really dont know where to start from on the code, and how make the PIC detect a pulse.

Comment: ... and your programming problem is? HW questions are OT [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how make the PIC detect a pulse.

2 ways that I can see:

1. If your input pins support interrupts for raising/falling events, then you can use those to detect the changes.
2. Alternative way is to poll inputs on your main loop and compare their state to previous iteration.

> I really dont know where to start from on the code

Read the manual for your microcontroller to find out what the pins can do, and how to initialize, read, write and optionally setup interrupts for them.

Toolchain and/or MCU documentation may have examples how to get started.

Comment: Started sutdying about polling after reading your answer and found a good solution. Thanks for your help.